# How does the fragment shader know what variable to use for the color of a pixel?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I see a lot of different fragment shaders,

```
#version 130

out vec4 flatColor;

void main(void)
{
    flatColor = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,0.5);
}
```

And they all use a different variable for the "out color" (in this case `flatColor`). So how does OpenGL know what you're trying to do?

I'm guessing this works because `flatColor` is the only variable defined as `out`, but you're allowed to add more `out` variables aren't you? Or would that just crash?

---

Actually, as a test, I just ran this:

```
#version 330

in vec2 TexCoord0;

uniform sampler2D TexSampler;

out vec4 x;
out vec4 y;

void main()
{
    y = texture2D(TexSampler, TexCoord0.xy);
}
```

It worked fine whether I used `x` or `y`.

(answer: the compiler is optimizing out the unused var, so the remaining var is assigned to location 0)

---

Furthermore, we have a predefined `gl_FragColor`. What's the difference, and why do people usually insist on using their own variables?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

> Furthermore, we have a predefined gl_FragColor.

Let's start with this. No, you *don't* have the predefined `gl_FragColor`. That was removed from core OpenGL 3.1 and above. Unless you're using compatibility (in which case, your 3.30 shaders should say `#version 330 compatibility` at the top), you should never use this.

Now, back to user-defined fragment shader outputs. But first, a quick analogy.

Remember how, in vertex shaders, you have inputs? And these inputs represent vertex attribute indices, the numbers you pass to `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and so forth? You set up which input pulls from which attribute. In GLSL 3.30, you use this syntax:

```
layout(location = 2) in color;
```

This sets the `color` vertex shader input to come from attribute location 2. Before 3.30 (or without ARB_explicit_attrib_location), you would have to either set this up explicitly with [`glBindAttrbLocation`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBindAttribLocation) before linking or query the program for the attribute index with [`glGetAttribLocation`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetAttribLocation). If you don't explicitly provide an attribute location, GLSL will assign a location *arbitrarily* (ie: in an implementation-defined manner).

Setting it in the shader is almost always the better option.

In any case, fragment shader outputs work almost exactly the same way. Fragment shaders can write to [multiple output colors](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment#Fragment_shader_outputs), which themselves get mapped to [multiple buffers in the framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Draw_Buffer). Therefore, you need to indicate which output goes to which fragment output color.

This process begins with the fragment output location value. It's set very similarly to vertex shader input locations:

```
layout(location = 1) out secColor;
```

There are also the API functions [`glBindFragDataLocation`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBindFragDataLocation) and [`glGetFragDataLocation`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetFragDataLocation), which are analogous to `glBindAttribLocation` and `glGetAttribLocation`.

If you don't do any explicit assignments, implementations usually will assign one of your output variables to location 0. However, the OpenGL standard does not *require* this behavior, so you should not depend on it either.

Now to be fair, your program should have *failed* to link when you used two outputs that didn't get different output locations. What probably happened was that your compiler optimized the one you didn't write to out, so it kinda forgot about it when it came time to check for linker errors.

Comment: Wish I could give more than +1.  Spectacular answer.  I was wondering how fragment output locations worked. :)

Comment: Ahh.. so they deprecated `gl_FragColor` in favor of giving you more flexibility to choose which buffer to write to? Makes sense. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mark: "Deprecation" means "you can still use it, but it may be removed in later versions." "Removed" means *removed*. There is a difference. That which was marked deprecated in GL 3.0 was **removed** in 3.1 (save for a couple of things).

Comment: @NicolBolas: Removed from the spec, maybe, but evidently not from my driver :P Anyway, wrong choice of words.

Comment: @NicolBolas is this only applicable if we aren't drawing to the screen? i.e. when drawing to an FBO? If we're just drawing to the screen, do we need to specify an output index (or use `glBindFragDataLocation`)?

Comment: @NicolBolas: "GL 3.3 and above (that's a change from prior versions) will assign them all to location 0". I wonder where this is guaranteed by the spec. 3.3 says "When a program is linked, any varying out variables without a binding specified [...]
or explicitly set within the shader text will automatically be bound to fragment colors and indices by the GL. All such assignments will use color indices of zero.". The last sentence is not present in 3.2. However, index does not refer to color _number_ but only to the dual source blending index (which was added in 3.3).

Comment: Thank you @NicolBolas, great answer! So I haven't quite understood it fully yet, and just want to make it "without question". In our shaders, we always specify `layout (location = 0) out vec4 outColor` when drawing to whatever is bound (most often "the screen" and not an FBO). So as default, if we haven't bound an FBO (or other buffer) using glDrawBuffers, and we specify `location = 0`, it will always draw correctly to the screen?

Comment: this was a bit confusing. i found out that there should be such "https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Default_Framebuffer" thing and there was.

Comment: Actually, pretty major nitpick: `gl_FragColor` and `gl_FragData` have only been removed from the core profile in GLSL 4.20, as the section 1.2.1 of [the GLSL 4.20 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.20.pdf) explicitly says. To my best understanding, this means that they *are* guaranteed to exist in earlier versions of the core GLSL, as long as the forward compatibility mode, which removes all deprecated features (and is unfortunately mandatory in Apple devices to obtain core OpenGL) is not used.

Comment: [CG did a really great job at this using : SEMANTICS](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_chapter02.html). It looked something like this : `void vertexShaderFunction( IN float3 incomingPosition : POSITION,  IN float3 incomingColor : COLOR, out float4 outgoingPosition : POSITION, out float4 outgoingColor : COLOR `

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to specify this for OpenGLES 3.1 which uses GLSL_ES_3.10 [link](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.1/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.10.pdf):

> §4.4.2
>
> If there is only a single output [in the fragment shader], the
>   location does not need to be specified, in which case it defaults to
>   zero.